# How to trigger Glue job using boto3 with different tag values for each run

Tags: boto3, aws-glue

I have a Glue job. I am triggering the Glue job from a lambda by passing dynamic arguments as below.

```
glue.start_job_run(JobName=gluejobname,
                                   Arguments=job_arguments)
```

Now, I have a requirement where each job run cost should be attributed to different team based on the `job_arguments` I am passing above.

For example.
For first Glue run, it receives as parameter named `team` with value `team1` and it runs for 1 hour.

For second Glue run, it receives as parameter named `team` with value `team2` and it runs for 2 hours.

Now I want to attribute first run cost to `team1` and send run to `team2`. I am looking for possibilities to pass tag values dynamically from lambda through `start_job_run` method.

I don't want to just duplicate creating multiple Glue jobs with static tag values for `team1` and `team2` as in reality there are multiple teams.

Comment: How do you trigger the lambda?

Answer (score 1):

**It's simply not possible.**

You would need to update tags on the Glue job before each run, however my bet is that AWS Cost Explorer would still only show breakdowns basing on the latest tag values.

Since having multiple Glue jobs is free, I would recommend:

- defining the Glue jobs using any IaC framework
- deploying multiple Glue jobs for each team (shouldn't be much trouble with AWS CDK for example)
- setting up proper tags for each Glue job as you described

By default the limit is 1000 of Glue jobs per account, which can be also increased

The only issue is monitoring multiple Glue jobs, however once again with IaC it shouldn't be that bad.